# Entity Framework custom config file

Tags: .net, entity-framework, wcf, architecture, config

my application based on wcf services architecture, and one of services is data access. this service have entity framework infrustructure(such as dbcontext, configuration file, poco classes..) and it set as console app. now also this services have a config file (app.config), but i need to avoid it. now this service start as single wcf-service. this means that for any request to database we need to do wcf-calls to data access and then call to database, but if we get rid of this service and reference this project by referencing dll, we will not do any wcf calls, and we can call database at once. for this puprose i need to refactor current approach of getting config values from app.config to another one. i want to save config file, but with other name like "db.config". all services which want to use database, will have this file in output directory, but i'am not sure that this approach is good. Give me recommendation or solution for my task.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have a base dll that does data access and some WCF projects that call that data access logic from the first dll, passing the database connection string in some way to the base dll.

What I do is move the database specific settings to the Properties/settings of the base dll, and then I add a config section in the calling services app.config to include those settings.

So, I would have, in my core wcf library, a web config like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>   </configSections>


  <!-- OTHER WCF LIBRARY SETTING STUFF -->


  <applicationSettings>
    <WcfServiceLibrary1.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="Setting1" serializeAs="String">
        <value>temp1</value>
      </setting>
    </WcfServiceLibrary1.Properties.Settings>   </applicationSettings> </configuration>
```

And in my WCF service I would copy those lines of interest (section and settings) as so:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <!-- Copied to WCF Service Web.config -->
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>



          <!-- OTHER WEB CONFIG STUFF -->


  <!-- Copied to WCF Service Web.config -->
  <applicationSettings>
    <WcfServiceLibrary1.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="Setting1" serializeAs="String">
        <value>temp1</value>
      </setting>
    </WcfServiceLibrary1.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>

</configuration>
```

[edited]
This works seamless, and you will have the setting available in the Library like this: `Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1'. This is inside an automaticly generated internal class, so to get access to the value of 'Setting1' in the service you can expose it via a simple class.